# How to create my own logging configuration for an Openfire Plugin

Tags: java, apache, xmpp, openfire

I have the following setup

Version:    Openfire 4.0.2
Server Directory:   /opt/openfire

Running on a Centos (6) machine.

I have a plugin and I run a lot of debug code when developing. I will get an instance of a Logger using:

```
private static final Logger Log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Submitter.class)
```

but the problem is that when I look at the logs (DEBUG level), I get EVERYTHING that has DEBUG (for example the httpd Apache libraries). I know that in JBOSS (and other systems) I can make a config that allows me to put Log Ouput of just my plugin to a specific location (e.g. a separate file).

Does anyone have any idea how to do this or if this is possible in Openfire?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Openfire installation, under lib directory, there's a config file named

```
log4j.xml
```

just modify this and override default one.

If you need a log4j tutorial, check out at: https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-xml-example

In you case you can:

- redirect your own classes in another custom file
- redirect all debug in another file and keep your custom class in
  default debug log so it will be viable by Openfire webinterface

Comment: Excellent - thank you so much. The file wasn't actually in the bin directory (it was in lib (for some unexplained reason!) but given that hint was enough for me to find it.

Comment: Yai sorry, when you deploy it is in lib, thanx, I edited the answer